# UItableview cell background color

Tags: uitableview

Hey guys i want to make the background of my cell color to be like this
.check the attached image.

thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u have to use gradients to get this look.take a look at this tutorial (gradients part) http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients

Answer (score 1):

INSIDE cellforrowind.... function

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

or

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha];
```

change those value with red ,green blue ,alpha

Comment: but that wont give me this color

Comment: dear...there need gradient effect